# alternate access mappings and list event handlers

Tags: event-handlers, alternate-access-mapping

I have a tricky problem with list event handlers (item checking in).. I deployed a site level feature with itemcheckingin event for sharepoint 2010.

If I access the sharepoint site using the url's defined in AAM, then event handlers work fine. But lets say any user uses a different url (by adding an entry to HOSTS file) then sharepoint does not trigger event handlers.

Is there any way to register event handlers regardless of the access url ? or am I doing something wrong while registering / configuring sharepoint ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of things that don't work when you access SharePoint from a URL not in the AAM.  My install actually gives a yellow screen of death when this is done.  I don't think accessing SP from a url that's not in AAM is supported in SP.

Just curious, why would a user be using an URL different from what's in the AAM?  And why would you want to support this?

An easy way to rid yourself of this is I would turn on host headers for the site in IIS to only include those that are in your AAM.

Comment: Hello, I don't wanna support this actually. I just want sharepoint to trigger the event handlers no matter what.. enforcing url's via site bindings (host headers for iis7 I guess) seems to be only solution. Thanks!